# SQL select column from other table with corresponding value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

`Suppliers` table

```
 Part Number Supplier

    XXX        A           
    XXX        B
    YYY        C
```

`Part Numbers` table

```
 PK_ID Part Number

   1        XXX
   2        YYY
```

I want to select it with additional column `FK_ID` based on `PK_ID` from `Part Numbers`:

```
 FK_ID Part Number Supplier

   1       XXX        A           
   1       XXX        B
   2       YYY        C
```

What doesn't work:

```
 SELECT s.`Part Number`, s.`Supplier`, p.`PK_ID` 
   FROM `Suppliers` AS s, `Part Numbers` AS p 
JOIN ON s.`Part Number` = p.`Part Number`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT s.`Part Number`, s.Supplier, p.PK_ID`
FROM Suppliers JOIN
     `Part Numbers` p 
     ON s.`Part Number` = p.`Part Number` ;
```

I would encourage you to name your tables and columns without spaces, so you don't need to escape the names.  Having to put a bunch of backticks in the SQL statement is just a distraction for writing or reading the query.

Comment: is correct.  Also, in the future you should try to use all lowercase when naming columns and tables and also replace your spaces in the names with an underscore.  For example, Part Number should be renamed to part_number or the part numbers table should be renamed to just parts and then you can name the part number column to just number then in your query it is more readable ie. (part.number).

Comment: It works! It's not possible to just add `FOREIGN KEY` column `FK_ID` that will automatically populate itself with corresponding IDs form `PK_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT s.`Part Number`, s.`Supplier`, p.`PK_ID`
FROM `Suppliers` AS s 
JOIN `Part Numbers` AS p ON s.`Part Number` = p.`Part Number`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using comma's before the `JOIN` in your query which is not allowed. You can instead use natural join because you have same column name `Part Number`

```
 SELECT `Part Number`, Supplier, PK_ID
  FROM Suppliers NATURAL JOIN
 `Part Numbers`;
```

Avoid using Column Name comprising of spaces instead use _ for joining name of columns

Refer the given links for more details: [Naming Conventions](https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/)

[Mysql table and column (field) naming conventions](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mysql-table-and-column-field-naming-conventions/1322)